# Whole text or title of news from the GDELT query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gdelt

I'm currently working on fetching data from the GDELT project using Google BigQuery. While exploring various tables, I haven't come across any that include the complete text or title of news articles. It appears that the tables primarily contain URLs linking to the news content. My question is whether there is a specific table within the GDELT project that includes the headline, title, or description of news articles, or if the tables solely consist of URLs.

For instance I've gone through

```
gdelt-bq.full.events
```

But it doesn’t contain the headlines and text of news.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDELT project does not contain the full text of news articles. The tables in the GDELT project only contain the URLs of the news articles. If you want to get the full text of news articles, you will need to use a different data source.